# Is there a TDEE calculator which takes into account sleeping hours?

Tags: sleep, calories

For the record, TDEE stands for 'Total Daily Energy Expenditure.' I have sleeping problems, which essentially require me to get ~12 hours of sleep a day. I'd assume this substantially lowers my TDEE, but I'd like to be able to calculate the effect more precisely. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several such calculators where you can input the hours you spend sleeping / sitting / standing etc. One example is [here](http://www.health-calc.com/diet/energy-expenditure-advanced).

Please note that even this will not give you a 100 percent accurate number.